# Store GMT time in mySQL table

Tags: mysql

Am looking for a way to store GMT timestamp in the table.

Currently I use something like UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()). But this will depend on which server my script is installed. In order to make it server-time agnostic, I want to store it in GMT time. I do not have any control over the server settings (like my.inf).

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to tell MySQL to connect to a time server.

On your client, you must connect to a machine which has the correct time and put that into 
the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement.

In practice, this doesn't work well. The best solution is to make sure that the server's time is correctly synchronized. Ask the admins to setup [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol). This will fix the issue at the source.

Comment: I was looking for something similar to gmdate in php

Answer (score 0):

You can tell MySql to use a particular time zone [MySql timezone doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html)